# High bandwidth usage from "Service Traffic" on only one ISP

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, ping, isp

I'm using NetBalancer and seeing a very odd behavior from windows. There's one element on the list "Service traffic".

I found the following information here https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4dv2o8/what_is_service_traffic_listed_in_netbalancer_it/

"Service Traffic is various non-TCP/IP traffic, like DNS requests, PINGs etc. Also on some configurations NetBalancer is unable to detect what some traffic belongs to, and assigns it to Service Traffic."

I have two internet connections (One is a low-speed backup) and there's barely any activity from Service Traffic on the backup connection. The main connection seems to be constantly maintaining 10-30 kb/s download, which is troublesome since my network usage is metered and this thing is downloading 600-700MB every day.
Upon some digging, it seems the new ISP is blocking ports. Ping doesn't work on the metered connection but works on the backup connection. I can't ask my ISP to open the port, is there any way to fix this?

This problem only occurs on Windows 10, other systems running Windows 7 on my network do not show this problem.

Comment: I presume you have ruled out that existance of a bug in the software?

Comment: I used another software (Networx) and it does seem to indicate a higher data usage on the first internet connection, unfortunately it doesn't show process specific data.

Comment: Have you ran a traffic capture to see what the constant 10-30kb/s download is? Close down all applications on your PC, start a capture and see what is connecting to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to figure it out. Turns out it was netbalancer itself which was causing the problem. After exiting the netbalancer service, data usage came back down to normal levels.